# What is the use of sp_addextendedproperty in SSIS packages?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to use sp_addextendedproperty for package audit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sp_addextendedproperty adds a new extended property to a database object and can be use in SSIS to create an Audit trail by adding package name, time it was run and count of rows deleted or updated during an ETL process